# How to ensure only specific attributes are updated and force another attribute to be nil in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts, whitelist, update-attributes

In RailsCasts [Episode #274 'Remember Me & Reset Password'](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast), the user enters their new password which submits to the `PasswordResetsController`.

The cast shows the line that updates the attributes to be:

```
elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

for Rails 4, I've had to change this to:

```
elsif @user.update_attributes(params.permit![:user])
```

I only want the user's `password` attribute to be updated with what the user has entered, and also set the `password_reset_token` to `nil`. How can I do that and also ensure only *those* fields can be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
elsif @user.update_attributes(
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation).merge(password_reset_token: nil)
)
```